# Postgres Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.postgresql.util.GT

Tags: java, postgresql, cassandra

I have a microservice which perform a healthcheck on one Cassandra and Postgres database. However, sometimes I get the following exceptions:

```
2018-12-05 09:28:40,336 ERROR [SubcriberService.java:403] Error while persisting the model onto database, All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
2018-12-05 09:30:15,392 ERROR [SubcriberService.java:403] Error while persisting the model onto database, All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
2018-12-05 09:32:01,581 WARN [HttpChannel.java:568] /healthcheck
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.postgresql.util.GT
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.postgresql.util.GT
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:272)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at fr.mycompany.computer.health.HealthCheck.doHealthCheck(HealthCheck.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
```

I can see two exception with:

- For cassandra --> Error while persisting the model onto database, All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
- For Postgres --> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.postgresql.util.GT

But in all fairness, I don't try to persist an entity in cassandra (only one select is made), and for postgres, I have the class GT in the postgres jar (postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar) ...

I don't really understand what happen ... because if I restart de microservice, everything works well ! And cassandra and postgres database, weren't down.

Do you have an idea ?

Best regards

Comment: [pgjdbc issue #1303 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.postgresql.util.GT](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1303) suggests the problem is caused by Out of Memory condition. Since restarting fixes the problem, it seems you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thank, that was the problem.